# how can i show one div and hide all the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a loop to this script to hide all other div after i press on one of them:

```js
function showHideDiv(id) {

  var obj = document.getElementById(id);

  if (obj.style.display == "none") {
    obj.style.display = 'block';

  } else if (obj.style.display == "block") {
    obj.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<li style="opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><a href="#guitars" onclick="showHideDiv('guitars')">Guitars</a>
</li>
<li style="opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><a href="#basses" onclick="showHideDiv('basses')">Basses</a>
</li>
<li style="opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><a href="#gallary" onclick="showHideDiv('gallary')">GALLLARY</a>
</li>




<div id="guitars" class="guitars" style="display: none;" class="mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark">
  <h2>Our Guiters</h2>
</div>
<div id="guitars" class="guitars" style="display: none;" class="mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark">
  <h2>Our Basses</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique. Share your html markup

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question?

Comment: Are you trying to construct "tabs" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly the following code might be of help to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var d = $('#parent > div').length;
$('#parent > div').click(function (e)
{
 
   var s = $('#parent > div').length -1;
  var z = $('div').index(this);
  for(i=0;i<=(s);i++){
    var y = z-1;
    if(i != y){
    $('#parent > div').eq(i).css('display','none');
      console.log('Index '+i+'has been hidden');
      }
       
  }
 
});


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "parent">
  <div>Guitars Basses GALLLARY</div>
  <div>Our Guiters</div>
  <div>Our Basses</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    //do something to each div like
    if (divs[i].style.display=="none"){
        divs[i].style.display='block';
    } else if(divs[i].style.display=="block"){
          divs[i].style.display='none';
    }
}
```

if you don't want to select all the divs you can assign a class to the divs you want and use the method:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('assignedclass')
```